# How to make the value showing on a Leaflet heatmap like this one?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heat-map, html, jquery

I'm attempting to use leaftlet.js, and heatmap.js (github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/) following [this example](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html):

But I want to show the value on the heat map like [this crime page](http://www.trulia.com/real_estate/San_Francisco-California/) (with two options on: "Crime Risk Layers" and "Reported Incident Markers"). And it is zoomable:

Here is the index.html using leaflet-heatmap.js, but not showing any values.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Leaflet Heatmap Layer Plugin</title>
    <style>
      body, html { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;}
      body { font-family:sans-serif; }
      body * { font-weight:200;}
      h1 { position:absolute; background:white; padding:10px;}
      #map { height:100%; }
      .leaflet-container {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8) !important;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="/plugins/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Leaflet Heatmap Layer Example</h1>
   <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

        var testData = {
          max: 8,
          data: [{lat: 24.6408, lng:46.7728, count: 3},{lat: 50.75, lng:-1.55, count: 1},{lat: 52.6333, lng:1.75, count: 1},{lat: 48.15, lng:9.4667, count: 1},{lat: 52.35, lng:4.9167, count: 2},{lat: 60.8, lng:11.1, count: 1},{lat: 43.561, lng:-116.214, count: 1},{lat: 47.5036, lng:-94.685, count: 1},{lat: 42.1818, lng:-71.1962, count: 1},{lat: 42.0477, lng:-74.1227, count: 1},{lat: 40.0326, lng:-75.719, count: 1},{lat: 40.7128, lng:-73.2962, count: 2},{lat: 27.9003, lng:-82.3024, count: 1},{lat: 38.2085, lng:-85.6918, count: 1},{lat: 46.8159, lng:-100.706, count: 1},{lat: 30.5449, lng:-90.8083, count: 1},{lat: 44.735, lng:-89.61, count: 1},{lat: 41.4201, lng:-75.6485, count: 2},{lat: 39.4209, lng:-74.4977, count: 1},{lat: 39.7437, lng:-104.979, count: 1},{lat: 39.5593, lng:-105.006, count: 1},{lat: 45.2673, lng:-93.0196, count: 1},{lat: 41.1215, lng:-89.4635, count: 1},{lat: 43.4314, lng:-83.9784, count: 1},{lat: 43.7279, lng:-86.284, count: 1},{lat: 40.7168, lng:-73.9861, count: 1},{lat: 47.7294, lng:-116.757, count: 1},{lat: 47.7294, lng:-116.757, count: 2},{lat: 35.5498, lng:-118.917, count: 1},{lat: 34.1568, lng:-118.523, count: 1},{lat: 39.501, lng:-87.3919, count: 3},{lat: 33.5586, lng:-112.095, count: 1},{lat: 38.757, lng:-77.1487, count: 1},{lat: 33.223, lng:-117.107, count: 1},{lat: 30.2316, lng:-85.502, count: 1},{lat: 39.1703, lng:-75.5456, count: 8},{lat: 30.0041, lng:-95.2984, count: 2},{lat: 29.7755, lng:-95.4152, count: 1},{lat: 41.8014, lng:-87.6005, count: 1},{lat: 37.8754, lng:-121.687, count: 7},{lat: 38.4493, lng:-122.709, count: 1},{lat: 40.5494, lng:-89.6252, count: 1},{lat: 42.6105, lng:-71.2306, count: 1},{lat: 40.0973, lng:-85.671, count: 1},{lat: 40.3987, lng:-86.8642, count: 1},{lat: 40.4224, lng:-86.8031, count: 4},{lat: 47.2166, lng:-122.451, count: 1},{lat: 32.2369, lng:-110.956, count: 1},{lat: 41.3969, lng:-87.3274, count: 2},{lat: 41.7364, lng:-89.7043, count: 2},{lat: 42.3425, lng:-71.0677, count: 1},{lat: 33.8042, lng:-83.8893, count: 1},{lat: 36.6859, lng:-121.629, count: 2},{lat: 41.0957, lng:-80.5052, count: 1},{lat: 46.8841, lng:-123.995, count: 1},{lat: 40.2851, lng:-75.9523, count: 2},{lat: 42.4235, lng:-85.3992, count: 1},{lat: 39.7437, lng:-104.979, count: 2},{lat: 25.6586, lng:-80.3568, count: 7},{lat: 33.0975, lng:-80.1753, count: 1},{lat: 25.7615, lng:-80.2939, count: 1},{lat: 26.3739, lng:-80.1468, count: 1},{lat: 37.6454, lng:-84.8171, count: 1},{lat: 34.2321, lng:-77.8835, count: 1},{lat: 34.6774, lng:-82.928, count: 1},{lat: 39.9744, lng:-86.0779, count: 1},{lat: 35.6784, lng:-97.4944, count: 2},{lat: 33.5547, lng:-84.1872, count: 1},{lat: 27.2498, lng:-80.3797, count: 1},{lat: 41.4789, lng:-81.6473, count: 1},{lat: 41.813, lng:-87.7134, count: 1},{lat: 41.8917, lng:-87.9359, count: 1},{lat: 35.0911, lng:-89.651, count: 1},{lat: 32.6102, lng:-117.03, count: 1},{lat: 41.758, lng:-72.7444, count: 1},{lat: 39.8062, lng:-86.1407, count: 1},{lat: 41.872, lng:-88.1662, count: 1},{lat: 34.1404, lng:-81.3369, count: 1},{lat: 46.15, lng:-60.1667, count: 1},{lat: 36.0679, lng:-86.7194, count: 1},{lat: 43.45, lng:-80.5, count: 1},{lat: 44.3833, lng:-79.7, count: 1},{lat: 45.4167, lng:-75.7, count: 2},{lat: 43.75, lng:-79.2, count: 2},{lat: 45.2667, lng:-66.0667, count: 3},{lat: 42.9833, lng:-81.25, count: 2},{lat: 44.25, lng:-79.4667, count: 3},{lat: 45.2667, lng:-66.0667, count: 2},{lat: 34.3667, lng:-118.478, count: 3},{lat: 42.734, lng:-87.8211, count: 1},{lat: 39.9738, lng:-86.1765, count: 1},{lat: 33.7438, lng:-117.866, count: 1},{lat: 37.5741, lng:-122.321, count: 1},{lat: 42.2843, lng:-85.2293, count: 1},{lat: 34.6574, lng:-92.5295, count: 1},{lat: 41.4881, lng:-87.4424, count: 1},{lat: 25.72, lng:-80.2707, count: 1},{lat: 34.5873, lng:-118.245, count: 1},{lat: 35.8278, lng:-78.6421, count: 1}]
        };

        var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
          'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
          }
        );

        var cfg = {
          // radius should be small ONLY if scaleRadius is true (or small radius is intended)
          "radius": 2,
          "maxOpacity": .8, 
          // scales the radius based on map zoom
          "scaleRadius": true, 
          // if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for colorization
          // if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map boundaries 
          //   (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
          "useLocalExtrema": true,
          // which field name in your data represents the latitude - default "lat"
          latField: 'lat',
          // which field name in your data represents the longitude - default "lng"
          lngField: 'lng',
          // which field name in your data represents the data value - default "value"
          valueField: 'count'
        };


        var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);

        var map = new L.Map('map', {
          center: new L.LatLng(25.6586, -80.3568),
          zoom: 4,
          layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
        });

        heatmapLayer.setData(testData);

        // make accessible for debugging
        layer = heatmapLayer;
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Another link that is relevant is [this one using heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-legend-tooltip.html):

It shows the value when our mouse is hovering over a point.

Comment: You need TEST Data (points) - but the source is only raster images http://tiles.trulia.com/tiles/crime_heatmap/13/1310/3166.png?opacity=0.65&v=20140114

Comment: Hi @Mapperz Thanks for the quick response. I have testdata in the index.html above.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a chloropleth map, not a heat map. A chloropleth map colors polygons and has sharp boundaries, whereas heatmap is an extrapolation of intensity at points. The colors are used here are same, so it may have confused. Hope [this example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) helps you in achieving what you want.